# How to add Gridview in body of sticky header in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem when I want to add gridview in body of **sticky_header**. It has problem when scroll. Anyone used to face this problem ?

Please help.

Thanks,

Sourn Visal

Comment: Post the code for a short, complete example app and you're more likely to receive help.

Comment: @TedHenry I have try to upload code, but Stackoverflow seem does not allow me to post code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 2 parameters in GridView:

shrinkWrap: true,
physics: ScrollPhysics(),